# Can the PS Vita play multiplayer games with the PSP?

Tags: ps-vita, psp

I'm familiar with the PS Vita's Cross-Play games, which can carry your Vita progress over to your PS3, or vice versa.

This got me to wondering if it was possible to play any of the PS Vita Store's downloadable PSP titles with someone using a PSP, assuming the game itself has multiplayer.

For example, if I tried to play *Dissidia Final Fantasy* on my PS Vita against a friend who was playing it on the PSP, would I be able to do this?

Comment: I believe this works. I cant find a concrete source but when I do, I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can play PSP games online with the PS Vita so long as the servers are still up and running.

Also, apparently if the original PSP game supported Ad Hoc mode, Ad Hoc mode will work on the PS Vita as well.

https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3792

Comment: "and all that"? Anything specific?

Comment: and all that, SIR!

Comment: What about local WiFi play?

Comment: @BenBrocka Edited answer with additional details.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Hm, if this is the case I wonder why Patapon 3 isn't on Vita. I initially assumed the missing games were due to online features

Comment: @Ben That's a good question.  The Vita plays PSP games through emulation, so perhaps some of the PSP games have to be re-engineered in some way to be compatible.